# Targeting a Table with name taken from cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add to specific Tables, based on the Table name in cell A2.
I'm unsure if I am searching with the right terminology but this is what I have no far, I obviously get a mismatch error:

```
Sub addToExistingTable()

    Dim tblname As ListObject
    Dim nNewRow As ListRow

    tblname = Range("A2").Value
    Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects(tblname).Range.Select
    Set nNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    nNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a decided ambiguity between the worksheet that `Range("A2")` is on and the worksheet where the table resides. However, reading further into the code seems to indicate that once you have selected the table you want to add the value from `Range("A1")` (again with no parent worksheet specified so must be on the same worksheet as the table just selected) into a new row on the table so `Range("A1:A2")` are almost assuredly on **Sheet1** (the same worksheet as the table).

```
Sub addToExistingTable()

    Dim tblname As String
    Dim nNewRow As ListRow

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        tblname = .Range("A2").Value

        With .ListObjects(tblname)
            Set nNewRow = .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
            nNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = .Range("A1").Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had hashed together the code above from my actual code which does specify sheets, as I've copying information from one sheet to another.

Comment: Your code worked on my test with String, not sure why it didn't work when I tried that. 

(Thank you also for reminding be about not using select, I have no excuse for that. I've seen that link so many times.)